# Like Hotjar's Ask but headless and open source

Tags: open-source, web-development, api, web

Hotjar has a nice feature that gives you a button on the bottom right of your page and then when a user clicks on it they can rate the application and give feedback (shown on the screenshot).

I am looking for something like this but open source so that I can host it myself and it should have an API that I can talk to directly (that's what I mean by headless) because I want to implement the feedback dialog UI myself. Then the feedback will be sent to the API and out of the tool will out of the box offer the UI (dashboards, etc.) to view those user feedbacks and make sense out of them.

Does anyone of you know something like this?

[image]